# How to make the response containing zip file using API Gateway + Lambda + PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, lambda, api-gateway

How to write code by PHP?

What I want looks like they clicked a link to download a zip file of images, and the response is the zip file of images.
On server side the images need to be retrieved, zipped, and returned to the user.
I've already done to code to download files and saved a zip file of them into lambda tmp directory.

How to return the zip file from lambda tmp directory to the user?

main_.php

```
function bulk_downloader($key) {
 $BUCKET_NAME = 'dse';
 $IAM_KEY = 'AKIAR****NV*******ONC';
 $IAM_SECRET = 'wuyuBMHTao8t*********RpGErxC1lo8odjp0JC';
 $IAM_REGION = 'us-east-2';
 $TMP_PATH = '/tmp/';

 $file = $TMP_PATH . rtrim($key, '/') . '.zip';
 try
 {
    $client = S3Client::factory(array(
        'credentials' => array(
            'key' => $IAM_KEY,
            'secret' => $IAM_SECRET
        ) ,
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => $IAM_REGION
    ));

    $client->registerStreamWrapper();
    $files = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', ['Bucket' => $BUCKET_NAME, 'Prefix' => $key]);
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

    foreach ($files as $f)
    {
        $contents = file_get_contents("s3://{$BUCKET_NAME}/{$f['Key']}");
        $zip->addFromString($f['Key'], $contents);
    }
    $zip->close();
 }
 catch (Exception $e) {
  die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
 }
 return $file;
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
include 'main_.php';

return function ($event) {
   $zip_file = bulk_downloader('img/');

   if (file_exists($zip_file)) {
     $file = file_get_contents($zip_file, true);
   } else {
     die("Error: File not found.");
   }
   unlink($zip_file);
   $headers = array(
     "Content-Type"=>"application/zip",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"=>"Content-Type",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" =>"OPTIONS,POST");
   return json_encode(array(
      "statusCode"=>200,
      "headers"=>$headers,
      "body"=>"$file"
   ));
};
```

Comment: People expect to see what you tried (your code), in a well formatted question. Help them help you. Please take the [**stack overflow tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know more about this site, and read about **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: Thanks, YvesLeBorg